# How to call directive template on click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a reusable modal dialog and I would like to load directive *template* on click directive itself..

```
function modalDialog() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: linkFunc,
            template: '<div class="modalBox--blur">' +
            '<div class="modalBox">' +
            '<h3>' {{title}} '</h3>' +
            '<h4>' {{text}} '</h4>' +
            '<button ng-click="answer(true)">Cancel</button>' +
            '<button ng-click="answer(false)">Ok</button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>',
            scope: {
                title: '=dialogTitle',
                text: '=dialogTxt'
            },
            transclude: true
        };

        return directive;

        function linkFunc($scope, element, attrs) {

            element.on('click', function () {
                $scope.newEl = element.parent();
                $scope.newEl.append(...template Here...???);
            });
        }
    }
```

This is how directive is set in the view:

```
<button
        modal-dialog
        dialog-title="modalBox.title"
        dialog-txt="modalBox.subText"
        type="button"
        ng-click="deleteSth()"
        class="button">
</button>
```

I can't figure out how to load template on element click :

```
 element.on('click', function () {
    $scope.newEl = element.parent();
    $scope.newEl.append(template????);
 });
```

Any tips? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the template with [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)
Like `$templateCache.get('templateId.html')`

Comment: That works almost as I want but I can't bind scope variables (title,text).. I guess you can't bind scope variables with $templateCache..

Comment: What do you mean? you mean there are some var binding in your template? Then you need an interpolate, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Answer (score 0):

Solution was compiling the template:

```
scope.modal = $compile(' <div class="modalBox--blur">' +
    '<div class="modalBox">' +
    '<h3>{{title}}</h3>' +
    '<h4>{{text}}</h4>' +
    '<button ng-click="dialogAnswer(true)">Annuleren</button>' +
    '<button ng-click="dialogAnswer(false)">Ok</button>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>')(scope);
element.on('click', function () {
    scope.newEl = element.parent();
    scope.newEl.append(scope.modal);
```